# Comparing array elements to character

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a simple javascript program to check if a letter is a vowel. The problem is the output is incorrect and should say that " a is a vowel."

Javascript:

```
function findvowel(letter1, vowels) {
    var count = vowels.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (vowels[i] === letter1) {
            var message1 = " is a vowel";
            document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message1;
        } else {
            var message2 = " is a consonant";
            document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message2;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        findvowel("a",["a","e","i","o","u"]);
    });
</script>
```

Output:

```
a is a consonant
```

Comment: first of all, your findvowel function shouldnt have a vowel parameter.  they don't change.

Comment: `function findvowel(letter) {
    return ["a","e","i","o","u"].indexOf(letter) != -1;
}` -> http://jsfiddle.net/6wnhL/1/

Comment: @adeneo - We need to go deeper: `/[aeiou]/i.test(letter);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `break` to your loop so it doesn't keep going.

```
function findvowel(letter1, vowels) {
    var count = vowels.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (vowels[i] === letter1) {
            var message1 = " is a vowel";
            document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message1;
            break;
        } else {
            var message2 = " is a consonant";
            document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message2;
        }
    }
}
```

You can actually use `return false;` to stop your function right away when a vowel is matched, however in normal cases `break` will be used because there might be other codes going on after the loop.

BTW:

```
function findvowel(letter){
    //thanks p.s.w.g for reminding me []
    return letter+" is a "+(/[aeiou]/i.test(letter)?"vowel":"constant");
}
```

Comment: Well for that matter `/[aeiou]/i`

Comment: Adding the break statements fixed it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You're testing the vowel in the `for`-loop and updating the output every time. So the output will only display if the *last* vowel that was tested matched the input. Instead, you should break out of the `for`-loop if a vowel is found, and only display a failure (`" is a consonant"`) after you've tested all the vowels and you weren't able to find a match:

```
var count = vowels.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (vowels[i] === letter1) {
        var message1 = " is a vowel";
        document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message1;
        return;
    }
}

var message2 = " is a consonant";
document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message2;
```

But this method could be simplified to:

```
function findvowel(letter1) {
    var isVowel = "aeiou".indexOf(letter1) > -1;
    var message = letter1 + " is a " + (isVowel ? "vowel" : "consonant");
    document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do, using native functions:

```
var letter = "a";
var isVowel = ["a","e","i","o","u"].some(function(vowel){
     return vowel === letter;
});
```

Rergarding your message, I would try something like:

```
var message =  letter + (isVowel ? " is a vowel" : " is a consonant");
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery, which offers $.inArray(), why don't you do this?

```
var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

$(document).ready(function() {

    var letter = 'u';

    var found = $.inArray(letter, vowels) > -1;

    if(found) {
        console.log(letter + ' is a vowel');
    } else {
        console.log(letter + ' is a consonant');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would pass in an object instead of an array and take advantage of the constant time lookup using the 'in' keyword. No need for a loop.

```
function findvowel(letter1, vowels) {
        if (letter1 in vowels) {
            var message1 = " is a vowel";
            document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message1;
        } else {
            var message2 = " is a consonant";
            document.getElementById('exercise3').innerHTML = letter1 + message2;
        }
}
```

then

```
var obj = {'a': true, 'e': true, 'i': true, 'o': true, 'u': true}
```

then call it

```
findvowel('a', obj)
```